# Constructor in base and derived class

Tags: c++, constructor, derived-class

Program works but I am not sure what is wrong with constructor since every time program runs it gets this error "warning: base class 'Alat' is uninitialized when used here to access 'Alat::ime' [-Wuninitialized]". I suppose it's something wrong how I called a constructor from base class but I am not sure what is problem. Really need help, tnx in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Alat{
protected:
    string ime;
    int serBr;
    int cena;

public:   

    void setIme(string i);
    string getIme();

    void setSerBr(int sb);
    int getSerBr();

    void setCena(int c);
    int getCena();

    Alat();
    Alat(string i, int sb, int c)
    :ime(i),
     serBr(sb),
     cena(c)
    {}

    void info();


    ~Alat();
};
```

---

```
#include "Alat.h"

class Rucni : public Alat{
protected:
    int minGodKor;

public:    

    Rucni():Alat(ime, serBr, cena)  //I think here is problem, is it wrong called?    
    {}

    int getminGodKor();
    void setminGodKor(int min);

    void info();

    ~Rucni();

};
```

Comment: You're trying to initialise `Alat` with `ime`, which is a member of `Alat`....

Comment: I'm pretty sure you get the warning when you run the program but when you compile it. It's important to learn the differences between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the child default constructor call the default parent constructor, and create another child constructor with parameters to call the corresponding one of the parent:

```
#include <string>

using std::string;


class Alat
{
protected:
    string ime;
    int serBr;
    int cena;

public:   

    void setIme(string i)
    {
        ime = i;
    }

    string getIme()
    {
        return ime;
    }

    void setSerBr(int sb)
    {
        serBr = sb;
    }

    int getSerBr()
    {
        return serBr;
    }

    void setCena(int c)
    {
        cena = c;
    }

    int getCena()
    {
        return cena;
    }

    Alat()
    {
    }

    Alat(string i, int sb, int c) : ime(i), serBr(sb), cena(c)
    {
    }

    ~Alat()
    {
    }
};


class Rucni : public Alat
{
protected:
    int minGodKor;

public:    

    Rucni() // implicit call of the parent default constructor
    {
    }

    Rucni(string i, int sb, int c) : Alat(i, sb, c) // explicit call of the corresponding parent constructor
    {
    }

    int getminGodKor()
    {
        return minGodKor;
    }

    void setminGodKor(int min)
    {
        minGodKor = min;
    }

    ~Rucni()
    {
    }
};


int main()
{
    Rucni r;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was calling get/set in Alat.cpp and could not make it to work, but this way it works, tnx so much!

Comment: Getters and setters are called after the object is created and initialized. Constructor is the first "method" called for the purpose of setting members to the desired value.